# Does Angular 2 have a way to store data in a JSON file?

Tags: angularjs, json, angular

Is there any way to read and write data in an Angular 2 application to a JSON file?

Comment: for security, client js script is not allowed to write files.

Comment: So do you have any suggestion about store data? Must we use backend server?

Comment: use localStorage as Edmar answer suggests. there is a 5 megabytes limitation, however anything bigger than that deserves better destiny... like a backend service, for instance. give us more datails and maybe other options can surface.

Comment: We have to build an application like Hacker News. We fetch news API from some sources and show them in our app. I meet the problem when trying to save the comment for each news we fetched. Because our project requires not to use back-end server.

Comment: btw, thank you @kirs & sombriks for useful information!

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not allowed.

You could use other ways to store your data, though.
One alternative would be using `localStorage`.

Take a look at [this article](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).